# How to get changed properties before updating in hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a use case where before updating an entity, and while still inside the service method, i need to find which properties of the entity were changed, and are about to be updated.

It is not possible to do this in a listener/interceptor as this action must be done in the context of the method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can map changed one to YourEntity tempObject = changed one, then compare that with old one

Answer (score 0):

You can inject this "context" into your interceptor through some thread local and do your work there. Something like this:

```
public void myService() {
  MyInterceptor.withContext(
    () -> {
        entityManager.merge(myEntity);
        entityManager.flush();
        // Your service logic
    },
    (oldState, newState) -> {
        // Your code
    }
  );
}

public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    private static final ThreadLocal<UpdateHandler> TL = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void withContext(Runnable r, UpdateHandler h) {
      try { 
        TL.set(h);
        r.run();
      } finally {
        TL.remove();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(
            Object entity, 
            Serializable id, 
            Object[] currentState, 
            Object[] previousState, 
            String[] propertyNames, 
            Type[] types) {
        UpdateHandler handler = TL.get();
        if (handler != null) {
          handler.onUpdate(previousState, currentState);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public interface UpdateHandler {
    public void onUpdate(Object[] oldState, Object[] newState);
}
```